# Jasmine beforeEach not called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Just starting with Jasmine and following the instructions on [the Jasmine website](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/upgrading.html) for async testing I notice the beforeEach function is never called.

Any idea why not?  I don't find any hints relevant anywhere on the web. Thanks.

**Code**

The code is really simple:

```
describe("Testing test.php", function()
{
    it ("Gets me a coke", function()
    {
        var asyncResult = null;

        // query function with callback
        var queryFcn = function(callback)
        {
            console.log("queryFcn");
            $.get("be_com/test.php?coke")
            .success(function(data)
            {
                asyncResult = data.response;
                callback(); // notify jasmine
            })
            .error(function() { callback(); });
        };

        // Call ajax
        beforeEach(function(done) { 
            console.log('beforeEach');
            queryFcn(done); });

        // Evaluate response
        expect(asyncResult).toBe("a can of coke");
    });
});
```

The HTML is equally simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../fe_com/js/lib/jasmine-standalone-2.3.4/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fe_com/js/lib/jasmine-standalone-2.3.4/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../fe_com/js/lib/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fe_com/js/lib/jasmine-standalone-2.3.4/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fe_com/js/lib/jasmine-standalone-2.3.4/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fe_com/js/lib/jasmine-standalone-2.3.4/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>

<!--   FILES -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="testSpec.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Unit Tests</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `beforeEach` block should not be inside of an `it` block.

The idea of a `beforeEach` is that the code inside it runs *before each of the following `it` blocks*. Example:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    // code in here will run 3 times
});

it('does first thing', function () {});
it('does a second thing', function () {});
it('does a third thing', function () {});
```